# Letting users manually sort items in a webapp

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I would like to make a simple web app that displays 20 or so images to users and lets them manually sort the images from favorite to least favorite, either by dragging or by using some form of up/down controls, and then submit this ordering. Are there existing tools, either in Javascript or Silverlight, that make this easy?

By the way, I'm thinking of using either Django or ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery UI has [sortables](http://dev.jquery.com/view/tags/ui/latest/demos/functional/#ui.sortable).

Answer (score 0):

I see you tagged using Silverlight, so I assume you are using ASP.NET technologies. You could use some variation of the ReorderList in the Ajax Control ToolKit:

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ReorderList/ReorderList.aspx

I'm sure there are hundreds of other such controls out there.